# How to check if a string contains a list of substring in Bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, substring, sh

for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

STR='foobar/group/dog/name'
SUB=["group/dog/name", "group/dog2/name"]

if [[ "$STR" contains *"$SUB"* ]]; then
  echo "It's there and print out the matching substring: group/dog/name"
fi
```

something like above, i'm still new to bash, can someone help with this please?
thanks.

Comment: Paste your script into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and implement the recommendations.   Then edit your question to include your updated script.

Comment: @j_b it just gave me output like `Expected test to end here (don't wrap commands in []/[[]])` which doesn't make sense to me and didn't resolve my original question!

Comment: You use '[ ]' in for tests in bash not for defining an array.  You would use '( )' and separate the array elements by spaces not comma-separated.  You would then need to loop through each element of the array and test to see if each element is a substring.  See the answer posted by @M.NejatAydin.

Comment: @wawawa, the [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports contain links to detailed information about problems, including how to fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do

```
#!/bin/bash

str='foobar/group/dog/name'
subs=('group/dog/name' 'group/dog2/name')

for sub in "${subs[@]}"; do
    if [[ $str = *"$sub"* ]]; then
        echo "$sub"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi what if `str` is also a list? is it the case just add one line `for str in "${str[@]}"; do`?

Comment: and what does `[@]`do here? thanks

Comment: arr[@] or arr[*] refers to all elements in an array

Comment: @wawawaw You may need nested loops if `str` is an array too, but this will be very inefficient for large number of array elements. `"${arr[@]}"` (double quotes are important here) expands array elements as a list.

Answer (score 1):

Building a regex with needle array and using `grep`

```
subs=('group/dog/name' 'group/dog2/name')
if echo 'foobar/group/dog/name' | grep -qE "$(IFS='|'; echo "${subs[*]}")"; then
  echo "FOUND"
fi
```

If stack is an array then it can be joined to test

```
srcstr=('some/group/dog/name' 'group/dog3/name')
subs=('group/dog/name' 'group/dog2/name')
if printf '%s' "${srcstr[@]}" | grep -qE "$(IFS='|'; echo "${subs[*]}")"; then
    echo "FOUND"
fi
```